# oracle global temporary tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I created the global temp table. when I execute the code as an individual scripts it works fine. but when I execute it as a single script in TOAD then no record was created. there was just an empty global temp table.

eg.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TRAN
(
COL1 NUMBER(9),
COL2 VARCHAR2(30),
COL3 DATE
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
/

INSERT INTO TEMP_TRAN VALUES(1,'D',sysdate);
/
INSERT INTO TEMP_TRAN VALUES(2,'I',sysdate);
/
INSERT INTO TEMP_TRAN VALUES(3,'s',sysdate);
/
COMMIT;
```

When I run the above code one statement at a time it works fine. But when I execute it as a script it runs fine but there was no records in temp table.

can anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you explicitly stated `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`, the only reason why the rows would seem to "disappear" is that TOAD is using more than one session (i.e. you're executing the script with Session A and querying the table with Session B -- which would see an empty table).

I don't use Toad much, but I know you can open several independent sessions with this tool.

What happens if you put the query `SELECT * FROM TEMP_TRAN;` at the end of your script immediately after the commit ?

Comment: Toad runs some scripts in a background session so the inserted rows "disappear" after that session quits.
Try it in SQL*Plus and you should see the rows as expected.

Comment: when I put the query SELECT * FROM TEMP_TRAN; at the end of my script immediately after the commit, The records shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you will need to refresh the data display within Toad so that it shows the changes within the table under the tabpage Data.